# Is there an izhanichen function in djnago

Tags: text

#serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers

#Create your serializers here.

from inventoryapp.models import Inventory

class InventorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = Inventory
fields = "**all**"

Comment: from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Inventory(models.Model): 
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    price = models.IntegerField() 
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField() 
    barcode = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def str(self):
        return self.name

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please take the time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, please correct the title (it currently says "djnago" instead of "django"), add proper tags regarding the language and/or frameworks and properly format the code. Right now it's a mess spanning from 1/3 in the question body, 1/3 in comments and 1/3 in an answer. Please ask the question properly and give details regarding what you want, what you tried, what you haven't, what worked and what hasn't and what errors you have.

Answer (score 0):

from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import (InventoryItemListAPIView,
InventoryItemCategoryListAPIView,
InventoryItemSortAPIView,
InventoryItemEditAPIView,
)

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('inventory/items/', InventoryItemListAPIView.as_view(), name='inventory_items_list'),
path('inventory/items/query/str:category/', InventoryItemCategoryListAPIView.as_view(), name='inventory_items_by_category'),
path('items/query/str:category/', InventoryItemCategoryListAPIView.as_view(), name='inventory_items_by_category'),
path('items/sort/', InventoryItemSortAPIView.as_view(), name='inventory_items_sort'),
path('inventory/items/int:item_id/', InventoryItemEditAPIView.as_view(), name='inventory_items_edit_delete'),
]

Views.py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Inventory
from .serializer import InventorySerializer
from rest_framework import status

#Create your views here

class InventoryItemListAPIView(APIView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
items = Inventory.objects.all()
serializer = InventorySerializer(items, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = InventorySerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

class InventoryItemCategoryListAPIView(APIView):
def get(self, request, category, *args, **kwargs):
items = Inventory.objects.filter(category=category)
serializer = InventorySerializer(items, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class InventoryItemSortAPIView(APIView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
items = Inventory.objects.all().order_by('-price')
serializer = InventorySerializer(items, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class InventoryItemEditAPIView(APIView):
def put(self, request, item_id, *args, **kwargs):
try:
item = Inventory.objects.get(id=item_id)
serializer = InventorySerializer(instance=item, data=request.data, partial=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
serializer.save()
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
except Inventory.DoesNotExist:
return Response({'error': 'Item not found'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

```
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


def delete(self, request, item_id, *args, **kwargs): 
    try: 
        item = Inventory.objects.get(id=item_id) 
        item.delete() 
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT) 
    except Inventory.DoesNotExist: 
        return Response({'error': 'Item not found'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).